# How to select a component of a sympy equation?

Tags: python, sympy, equation

I would like to know if it is possible to select the compotent of a given term of an equation. For example in the photo below. I got that result for a tensor component and I wanna know if it is possible for me to get only the coefficient of the term that accompanies the (e-1)^4 (without having to copy it by hand).

[image]

Comment: It looks as if your code is using floats in a situation where exact rationals would be better so you could use e.g. `Rational(1, 3)` or `S(1)/3` rather than `1/3` which gives a float.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `coeff` method:

```
>>> eq = 3*y*(1 - x)**4 + 2*y*(1 - x)
>>> eq.coeff((1-x)**4)
3*y
```

Comment: I tried using coeff but got an error

```coef00 = eq.coeff()

NameError: name 'ε' is not defined
```

Comment: Without the code to recreate the expressions, it's hard to help. You can get an ordered list of variables from the expressions with `list(ordered(eq.free_symbols))`. With the example I gave, `x, y = list(ordered(eq.free_symbols))`. You might have more symbols so you can assign them to more variables (lambda, eps, r, ... = list(ordered(yourexpr.free_symbols))`.